# How to set up a flag to in entrypoint of docker container

Tags: bash, docker

I have Dockerfile with entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c", "source /code/entrypoint.sh | ts '[%Y-%m-%d 
%H:%M:%S]' &>> /output/stderr.log"]
```

and command  in entrypoint.sh:

```
fmriprep /input /output participant --fs-license-file 
/opt/freesurfer/license.txt --use-aroma --ignore fieldmaps --n_cpus 12 -- 
force-bbr --participant_label "${ids[@]}" -w /output
```

How could i set flags for command inside entrypoint for example add flag --some_flag to fmriprep command to run it with

```
docker run my_image --some-flag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass some environnement variable from you run command to your CMD before the "cmd" is triggered.
To do such, try using the '[-e](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)' clause this way (not tested, but should work):

```
docker run my_image -e 'EXTRA_OPTS=--some-flag'
```

and in your command :

```
fmriprep /input /output participant --fs-license-file 
/opt/freesurfer/license.txt --use-aroma --ignore fieldmaps --n_cpus 12 -- 
force-bbr --participant_label "${ids[@]}" -w /output $EXTRA_OPTS
```

That's the basic idea

Comment: It makes sense, no more than 1 flag?

Comment: No you can pass as many as you can within the "EXTRA_OPTS". It's better to use only one env var for all of them because this was this is predictable : this will be the ONE env var for all you extra flags. This should be stg like 'EXTRA_OPTS="--some-flag --some other flag"' (to be tested!)

Answer (score 0):

Pass an environment variable:

```
docker run -e flag=somevalue my_image
```

You can access flag via `$flag` inside your `Dockerfile` which you can pass to your `script`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the JSON-array form of `ENTRYPOINT`, then everything in `CMD` is passed as command-line arguments to the entrypoint.

I would encourage not trying to write complex scripts inline in a `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml` file.  Write an ordinary script, `COPY` it into the image, and make that script the `ENTRYPOINT`.  It can refer to the shell variable `"$@"` to run its `CMD`.

For example, I could refactor your script into:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# I am /entrypoint.sh
"$@" | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' &>> /output/stderr.log
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# I am /run.sh
fmriprep /input /output participant --fs-license-file  /opt/freesurfer/license.txt --use-aroma --ignore fieldmaps --n_cpus 12 --force-bbr --participant_label "${ids[@]}" -w /output $EXTRA_OPTS
```

And then write a Dockerfile:

```
...
COPY entrypoint.sh run.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

And then you would get to run:

```
docker run my_image /run.sh --some-flag
```

You would also get to run ordinary debugging commands like:

```
docker run --rm -it my_image /bin/sh
docker run --rm my_image cat /run.sh
```

In this specific example I would probably rely on some external system to format and capture the log messages and not try to do it inside the container.  Routing Docker container logs to logstash, for instance, is a pretty typical setup.